# Navigating to a child route with parameters using Flutter and GetX

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, riverpod

I recently changed my code to work with GetX instead of Riverpod. With riverpod and autoroute I was able to navigate to a child route and also pass parameters to the child at the same time. I want to mimick that with GetX.

My code is structured like below. You should be able to copy and paste the code and run it after resolving dependencies. I've tried using GetMaterialApp.router, but that screws up all the navigation across my app and I'm not able to route with the normal methods available, there were also additional issues like:

- the homecontroller already being initialized, so when navigating a new controller was created before the old was destroyed
- or in the case that I didnt destroy the old controller there were two many scroll controllers attached to my pageview
- or the GetMaterialApp wasnt initialized before I tried to navigate when navigation was triggered from deeplink on app load

I've tried countless solutions and am unable to find anything that works well.

I need to be able to navigate to the listview route to a specific index in the list when deeplinks and notification handlers are triggered.

There are additional comments in the code that can give more info

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables, prefer_const_constructors

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:scrollable_positioned_list/scrollable_positioned_list.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  State<App> createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    initDeepLinks();
    super.initState();
  }

  void initDeepLinks() {
    //run some code that checks for link upon app start
    //if link is found, navigate to page

    //Navigate to home page with tabs then to page 1 with listview and initial index
    //Also, what if this gets called before material app is loaded?
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () => navigateToPage());

    //start a stream that listens to links
    //if link is found, navigate to page
    // navigateToPage();
  }

  navigateToPage() {
    //something to the effect of this but with GetX

    //  ref.read(pimRouterProvider).pushAndPopUntil(
    //       HomeRoute(children: [
    //         Page1Route(initialIndex: data['id'])
    //       ]),
    //       predicate: (route) => false,
    //     );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      initialBinding: HomeBindings(),
      initialRoute: "/home",
      getPages: [
        GetPage(
          // middlewares: [AuthGuard()],
          name: '/home',
          page: () => const HomePage(),
          binding: HomeBindings(),
          children: [
            GetPage(
              name: "/page1",
              page: () => const Page1(),
            ),
            GetPage(
              name: "/page2",
              page: () => const Page2(),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

// class App extends StatelessWidget {
//   const App({super.key});

// }

class HomePage extends GetView<HomeController> {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: false,
      body: PageView(
        controller: controller.pageController,
        onPageChanged: (value) => controller.onPageSelected(value),
        children: controller.pages,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: HomeNavBar(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeController extends GetxController
    with GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final RxInt _selectedIndex = 0.obs;
  int get selectedIndex => _selectedIndex.value;
  final pages = [
    const Page1(),
    const Page2(),
  ];
  late PageController pageController;

  @override
  void onInit() async {
    pageController = PageController(initialPage: selectedIndex, keepPage: true);
    super.onInit();
  }

  void onPageSelected(int index) {
    _selectedIndex.value = index;
  }
}

class HomeBindings extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut<HomeController>(() => HomeController(), fenix: true);
  }
}

class HomeNavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeNavBar({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.find<HomeController>();
    return Obx(() => NavigationBar(
          onDestinationSelected: (index) => controller.pageController
              .animateToPage(index,
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                  curve: Curves.easeIn),
          selectedIndex: controller.selectedIndex,
          destinations: [
            const NavigationDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.abc),
              label: 'page1',
            ),
            const NavigationDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
              label: 'page2',
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page1({this.initialIndex, super.key});

  final int? initialIndex;

  int getInitialScrollIndex(List<int> items) {
    int initScrollIndex = items.indexWhere((item) {
      return item == initialIndex;
    });
    if (initScrollIndex >= 0) {
      return initScrollIndex;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final items = List<int>.generate(100, (i) => i + 1);
    return Scaffold(
      body: ScrollablePositionedList.separated(
        itemCount: items.length,
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(items[index].toString()),
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(
          thickness: 1,
          height: 1,
        ),
        initialScrollIndex:
            initialIndex == null ? 0 : getInitialScrollIndex(items),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page2({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text('Page 2'),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // this is the riverpod code I want to replace with GetX
            // should be callable from anywhere in the app

            //  ref.read(pimRouterProvider).pushAndPopUntil(
            //       HomeRoute(children: [
            //         StudiesTab(children: [
            //           StudiesListRoute(initialIndex: data['id'])
            //         ])
            //       ]),
            //       predicate: (route) => false,
            //     );
          },
          child: const Text('Go to Page 1'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

My current code for navigating looks like this when the app is foregrounded (without scrolling).

```
 if (Get.find<AuthService>().loggedIn) {
          //scroll to study with new instances
          if (Get.isRegistered<HomeController>()) {
            Get.until((route) => route.settings.name == Routes.home);
            Get.find<HomeController>().pageController.jumpToPage(0);
          }
        }
```

Comment: *GetX instead of Riverpod.* I am just curious why

Comment: I like the architecture, services, & controllers setup. Plus i needed some of the addition no context stuff. @YeasinSheikh

Comment: afaik, you might face many troubles  with it. Package isn't updated for last 20 months